# how to add refer to friend option on my order page

Tags: magento2

I want share product link that I had order, for that added email option on my order page in , but dont know what should i write at herf in anchor tag i.e that will redirect to refer to friend page

Comment: please share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an idea from below code:

```
<?php foreach($items as $_item): ?>
    <?php $hreflink = $block->getUrl('sendfriend/product/send', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => ['id' => $_item->getProductId()]]); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $hreflink; ?>">Refer to Friend</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Code not tested.**

Comment: its working perfectly !  just i need do some changes like get $items .can u explain why u used  '_use_rewrite' => true

Comment: If its working. Kindly accept it so that it will help other developers in future.

Comment: Tick the green mark near my answer to accept it as solution.